# Snake lemma for equivalence relation

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

A sequence $$E(\zeta) \stackrel{\theta}{\to}  X^2 \rightrightarrows X  \stackrel{\zeta}{\to}    Y $$
where the unlabelled arrows are the two projection, is said to be *exact* iff

- $\zeta$ is  the coequalizer of $ p_1  \theta$ and $ p_2  \theta$
- $\theta$ is equalizer of $\zeta  p_1$ and $\zeta  p_2$.

I do know that these kind of structures where studied by Barr, but probably they where investigated in many contexts. My feeling, which I hope will be confirmed, is that the right environment for the subject are [regular categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+category).

> Can you name some general reference about these structure?

To be more precise, I am interested in a kind of snake lemma for this kind of exact sequences.

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llll}
 E(f) & \ra{p_i \circ \theta} & X & \ra{f} & Y  \\
\da{g_1} & & \da{g_2} & & \da{g_3} & & \\
E(v) & \ra{q_i \circ \eta} & V & \ra{v} & Z & \\
\end{array}
$$

> Can I find a map $E(g_3) \to E(v)/E(f)$? Or, more in general, was such a question investigated?

Comment: This sounds like the sort of thing that might be in the book of Borceux and Bourn, but perhaps they start by imposing further conditions on your category that are too restrictive for your purposes. (That said, one of their main aims is to work with good categories that are not additive; is this the kind of thing you want?)

Comment: Yes it is, thanks for the reference. I will give a look.

Comment: I will give a better look to the book but the hypothesis of Malcev is way too strong for me.

Comment: I feared as much. In that case I do not know of a suitable reference. Perhaps you could ask on the category theory mailing list?

Comment: How do you define $E(v)/E(f)$?

Comment: That is a very good question, I spent the whole yesterday trying to do so. Still I am trying.

Comment: Is $E(g_3)\to ... \to Z$ always exact?

Comment: No, in general it is not. $g_3$ must be al least surjective to be so.

Comment: I would go to the original reference for Barr-exact categories, with the warning that you shouldn't expect to do homology theory in an exact (let alone regular) category. There's a reason Borceux-Bourn called them *homological* categories. In particular, I don't see how one would hope to define $E(\nu)/E(f)$ without being in a pointed category, and realistically much more than that. Here's Barr's original, if you can pass Springer's paywall: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBFb0058580.pdf

Comment: @KevinCarlson, on one hand you must be right. On the other, one can prove that when $g_i$ is a regular epi for all $i$ then the sequence $E(g_1) \rightrightarrows E(g_2) \to E(g_3)$ is exact (At least, I think I proved it). This kind of motivates me in the direction that something should be true.

In this spirit I asked the following question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2629757/snake-lemma-and-regular-epi-mono-factorization

But still, the subject is cloudy to me and I do believe you are right.